# Continuous Min-Max problem

Tags: mathematical-optimization

Being new to Mathematica, I tried my best to find some built-in functions or guides on how to solve the classical min-max problem

$$ \min_{x} \max_{k} f(x,k,params) $$

with some additional variables $params$ and some *simple* constraints on the variables (e.g., $x\in [x_{min},x_{max}]$ and $k\in [k_{min},k_{max}]$) in the Mathematica language. Finding none (giving a link would be much appreciated), my approach was to first define function computing
$$ \max_{k} f(x,k) $$
e.g.,

```
fMax[x_,params_] := 
  FindMaximum[{f[x,k,params_], k > kmin, k < kmax}, {k, kinit}];
```

with a parameter $x$ and then minimize `fmax`, e.g.,

```
fMinMax[x_,params_] := 
  FindMinimum[{fMax[x_,params_], x > xmin, x < xmax}, {x, xinit}];
```

However, the following error is consistently raised.

```
FindMaximum::nrnum: The function value -((9.27923*10^11-2.95367*10^10 p)/(5.15531*10^17+1.64099*10^16 p)) is not a real number at {k} = {10.}.
```

although upon evaluating the function at that given point, the value is indeed real. I would be glad for any help. To give the full setting $f$ amounts to

$$ f(x,k,a,b,\alpha) = \frac{\frac{k\pi}{b} \cosh \left(\frac{k\pi}{b} (a-\alpha)\right) + x \sinh \left(\frac{k\pi}{b} (a-\alpha)\right)}{\frac{k\pi}{b} \cosh \left(\frac{k\pi}{b} (a+\alpha)\right) + x \sinh \left(\frac{k\pi}{b} (a+\alpha)\right)} $$

where $a,b,\alpha$ are positive parrameters such that $a>\alpha>0,b>0$.

Comment: Maybe `Minimize[MaxValue[f[x, k], x], k]` ? This can solve some simple problems.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I will check it out but I was honestly hoping for a fix of the above or even better explanation why it doesn't work. I feel like I must have missed some basic syntax or somthing like that.

I feel like the error message is telling me that for the inner function the call took place without specifying the inner parameter - and that's why Mathematica thinks it's not a number - but don't know if that si indeed the case and if so then how to fix it.

Comment: Are these `ResourceFunction`'s useful to you? [`ResourceFunction["GeneralMiniMaxApproximation"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/GeneralMiniMaxApproximation) and  [`ResourceFunction["MiniMaxApproximation"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/MiniMaxApproximation)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a number of problems with your code. First of all: you have patterns (`_`) on the r.h.s. of the assignments. Second: for these sort of problems, it's best to restrict your function values to numerical inputs (by matching with `_?NumericQ`) wherever you can. Here's a quick example with parameters I randomly picked to get you going:

```
f[x_, k_, {a_, b_, α_}] := (k π/b Cosh[k π/b (a - α)] + x Sinh[k π /b (a - α)])/
   (k π/b Cosh[k π/b (a + α)] + x Sinh[k π/b (a + α)])
kmin = 0;
kmax = 10;
xmin = -10;
xmax = 10;
fMax[x_?NumericQ, params_] := With[{
   max = FindMaximum[
      {f[x, k, params], k > kmin, k < kmax},
      {k, Mean[{kmin, kmax}]}
    ]
   },
   ksol = k /. max[[2]]; (* store the found value of k *)
   max[[1]]
 ];

fMinMax[params_] := FindMinimum[
    {fMax[x, params], x > xmin, x < xmax},
    {x, Mean[{xmin, xmax}]}
];
```

Test that `fMax` returns numerical values:

```
fMax[1, {1/10, 1, 1/10}] 
ksol
```

> 0.833333

> 0.00134382

Do the full min-max problem:

```
fMinMax[{1/10, 1, 1/10}]
ksol
```

> {0.333333, {x -> 10.}}

> 0.00277709

## Update

Some documentation about pattern constraints:

http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Patterns.html

https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumericQ.html

Documentation about `With`:

http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ModularityAndTheNamingOfThings.html

https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/With.html

[What are the use cases for different scoping constructs?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/559/what-are-the-use-cases-for-different-scoping-constructs)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The 'first of all' is a clear mistake on my part while writing the question here. I will try to find out more about the syntax you used - I am not familiar with `_?NumericQ` and the `With` statement in the definition. (In case you know of an easy resource to learn those, it would eb appreciated but if it is a common thing, it should be OK either way).
As soon as I get this thing going in ym set-up, I'll mark the answer as correct :).

Comment: @michalOut Sure, see the "Update" section ;)

Comment: I am very sorry that it took me several days to get back to this as you have responded so quickly in the first place. Nonetheless I think that I am getting the jist of it, thank oyu very much :).
However, to be sure - when you define the local variable for fMax I guess you meant to use FindMaximum rather than FindMinimum as we wanna solve a min-max not a min-min problem.

Comment: @michalOut Oops, good point. I think I had that at some point, but I was tinkering around with the code so much that I messed that up somewhere. I updated the answer.

Comment: Perfect, thank you @Sjoerd Smit . Maybe one more question if I may :
If I would like to have $k$ as only integers in the given interval $[k_{min},k_{max}]$, I know I can just add "$k \in $ Integers". Is there another way to do this? If not, the correct syntax is the following, right?

`{  max = FindMaximum[{f[p, k, params], k>kmin, k<kmax, k \[Element] Integers}, {k, 
    Floor[ Mean[{kmin, kmax}]] }]  }`

Comment: @michalOut I think that's the way to do it, yes, but it only works for linear programming problems (which your problem isn't). You can't do gradient-based methods on integers, so I don't know how you'd do this with `k` constrained to integers. It's a completely different -and much more difficult- problem, tbh. For example, the following doesn't work: `FindMaximum[{-(x - Pi)^2, x \[Element] Integers}, {x, 1}]`

Comment: @michalOut Actually, it looks like `NMaximize` might work: `NMaximize[{-(x - Pi)^2, x \[Element] Integers}, x]`. You should give that a try.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I am aware of the mathematical difference of the problems but as I am not an expert I didn't know whether we have numerical methods to treat both of these. Indeed `NMaximize` and `NMinimize` work both like a charm - in both cases where $k\in Reals$ or $k\in Integers$.

For anyone reading through - if you want to switch to `NMaximize`, it seems you cannot provide an initial guess ;).

Comment: To @Sjoerd Smit.  There is a typo in your definition of f. According to the TEX expression in the OP it should be `f[x_, k_, {a_, 
   b_, \[Alpha]_}] := (k \[Pi]/b Cosh[k \[Pi]/b (a - \[Alpha])] + 
    x Sinh[k \[Pi]/b (a - \[Alpha])])/(k \[Pi] /b Cosh[
      k \[Pi]/b (a + \[Alpha])] + x Sinh[k \[Pi]/b (a + \[Alpha])]) ` .  `k \[Pi] /b Cosh .....`  not `k \[Pi] b Cosh .....` in the denominator . With that correction, you get a fMinMax independent of b `fMinMax[{1/10, 10, 1/10}] `  gives `{0.333332, {x -> 10.}} ` the same as my analytical result.

Comment: @Akku14 Good eye. That just goes to show why everyone should post copy-able code in a question and not LaTex or pictures ;).

Answer (score 1):

You can get an analytical min max expression for x>=0.

With graphical means, i derived, that the max w.r.t. k is always at k==0.

**Edit**
Proof, that f reaches maximum at k==0.

Since Sinh and Cosh are greater zero for their argument greater zero, the numerator of f is always smaller than the denominator, exept for k==0 both are equal, means the maximum is at k==0.

```
f[x_, k_, a_, b_, \[Alpha]_] = 
     (k \[Pi]/b Cosh[k \[Pi]/b (a - \[Alpha])] + 
     x Sinh[k \[Pi]/b (a - \[Alpha])])/(\[Pi] k/b Cosh[
     k \[Pi]/b (a + \[Alpha])] + x Sinh[k \[Pi]/b (a + \[Alpha])])

Reduce[{TrigExpand[(k \[Pi] Cosh[(k \[Pi] (a - \[Alpha]))/b])/b < (
 k \[Pi] Cosh[(k \[Pi] (a + \[Alpha]))/b])/b], 0 <= k, 0 < x, 
  0 < \[Alpha], 0 < a, 0 < b}] // 
Simplify[#, {0 <= k, 0 < x, 0 < \[Alpha], 0 < a, 0 < b}] &

(*   k > 0   *)
```

The same for x Sinh[.....]

```
Reduce[{TrigExpand[(k \[Pi] Cosh[(k \[Pi] (a - \[Alpha]))/b])/b == (
 k \[Pi] Cosh[(k \[Pi] (a + \[Alpha]))/b])/b], 0 <= k, 0 < x, 
  0 < \[Alpha], 0 < a, 0 < b}] // 
  Simplify[#, {0 <= k, 0 < x, 0 < \[Alpha], 0 < a, 0 < b}] &

(*   k == 0    Again the same for Sinh   *)


lim[x_, a_, b_, \[Alpha]_] = 
    Limit[f[x, k, a, b, \[Alpha]], k -> 0, Direction -> -1]

(*   (1 + a x - x \[Alpha])/(1 + a x + x \[Alpha])   *)

Manipulate[
   Plot3D[{0, f[x, k, a, b, \[Alpha]] - lim[x, a, b, \[Alpha]]}, {x, 0, 
     10}, {k, 0, 10}, AxesLabel -> {x, k, f}, PlotRange -> All, 
     PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}], {{a, 1}, 0, 60, 
     Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{\[Alpha], 1/2}, 0, a, 
     Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{b, 1}, 0, 50, 
     Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

For x<0 you get singularities where the maximum over k is infinity.

The minimum over x>0 of the maximized values over k is then

```
min = Minimize[{lim[x, a, b, \[Alpha]], {0 <= x < 10, 
         0 < \[Alpha] < a, 0 < b}}, x]

(*   (1 + 10 a - 10 \[Alpha])/(1 + 10 a + 10 \[Alpha])   .....   *)
```

Get graphical confirmation of this result (minimum of the red curve).

```
Manipulate[{Plot[{lim[x, a, b, \[Alpha]], f[x, 1/2, a, b, \[Alpha]], 
f[x, 3, a, b, \[Alpha]], f[x, 10, a, b, \[Alpha]]}, {x, 0, 10}, 
  AxesLabel -> {x, lim}, PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue, Magenta}], (
  1 + 10 a - 10 \[Alpha])/(1 + 10 a + 10 \[Alpha]) // N}, {{a, 30}, 
 0, 60, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{\[Alpha], 1}, 0, a, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{b, 30}, 0, 150, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]